# iOS Navigation Controller doesnt add navigation bar

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

My situation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTlVu.png

I have two views right now. From the second view, I want to have a back button that goes back to the initial view. I added a navigation controller and made it the initial view, and the navigation bar appeared for the first view(PlusCalendar). However, I don't know how to add a navigation bar for the second view(AddEventControllerVC) and add a back button that makes it go back to PlusCalendarView. I have looked at several tutorials and none of them surprisingly dealt with this problem. I am also looking at Apple's class [reference](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationItem/initWithTitle:) and I am not sure if I have to initialize the navigation bar again from the second view controller. My questions are..

1. How come a navigation bar is not automatically added to all of my views?
2. For the second view, why does the navigation bar seem to be placed at the bottom?
3. How do I add a navigation bar on top of the second view, and add a "back" button?

Answer (score 0):

The navigation bar was supposed to add the back button automatically. The problem was that the sigue between my first view and second view was set as a "modal popover." When I changed it to a "push" the back button appeared rightfully.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in model pop, the navigation bar is not record the view controller in its stack. So it cannot known the back track.In your case ,you should custom your navigation items in the second view controller. You can look this example:  [custom navigation bar](http://rogchap.com/2011/06/21/custom-navigation-bar-background-and-custom-buttons/)